# Structuring Output Folders in Buck

Tags: buck

I am working on a project that uses Buck for its build system, and I want to have buck build a set of shaders. It is my understanding that I would use `genrule` to generate these shaders. The problem that I run into is that I need to specify the location of the shaders output relative to the main binary so that I can run them later. Is there a way to structure this with buck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally not possible to do that directly. The standard way to access the output a `genrule` is to use [`location`](https://buckbuild.com/rule/genrule.html) macro.

If your binary requires input data to be in a fixed location relative to the binary or current directory, you can work around that limitation by creating symlinks to the output of `genrule`. To do that you need to add a wrapper script which would create a link to the output of a `genrule` and then call the main binary.

Comment: So if I wanted to package this for release, I would have to have some sort of postprocess script?

Comment: Yes, your would have to have a postprocessing script which would place outputs of rules in a right locations.

Comment: Actually, I figured out how to do it, and I'll post the details soon. I think I may not have structured the question well enough.